# android PopupWindow from a fragment

Tags: android, popup, android-fragments

I have an app that uses fragments, its working ok,
but I have now to implement some pop ups when a button gets tapped,

I am following [this tutorial "Example of using PopupWindow"](http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

But I get this errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable
    - The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type new 
     View.OnClickListener(){}
```

here my .java

```
public class Tab2HeadH1 extends Fragment   implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2_head_buttons, container,false);

        //Buttons

        Button buttonNose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_pop_nose);

        buttonNose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
              //aqui tus tareas,,

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  //ERRORS HERE!!

               View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                          popupView, 
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            }


        });


        Button buttonEye = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_pop_eye);

        buttonEye.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
               // onLoginClicked(v);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ss9 eye",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



        ((TabActivity)getActivity()).setHeader("TAPING APPLICATION");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {



        }
    }


}
```

SO, how can I fix this problem??, to show my pop up from tapped button in my fragment??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

call

`LayoutInflater layoutInflater =     (LayoutInflater)**getActivity()**.getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Atleast it won't show error onBaseContext() as now it take from the associated activity

EDIT

Try this,

`LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: hi thanks, i have now LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); ,, but I get this error: LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a 
 variable,, how to fix this please? thanks!

Comment: actually you are calling it from fragment and it need context from activity so it was not recognizing the services. moment it gets context it works well.

Answer (score -1):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container,false);
    //inside button onclick write the code given below
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.address, null);
}
```